External Error While running shopify theme development
Error coming from bundle install

Command failed with exit code 5: bundle install
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Users/star/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.3.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1
for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Users/star/AppData/Local/shopify-gems-nodejs/Cache/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/wdm-0.1.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing wdm (0.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
In Gemfile: wdm
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...your text
Installing wdm 0.1.1 with native extensions


If you are using Windows I fixed this problem with these steps:

Uninstall Ruby: Remove Ruby through the Windows "Programs and Features" section.

Delete Folders: Delete all Ruby and MSYS folders from the C drive.

Install Ruby+Devkit: Install Ruby+Devkit 3.1.2-1 (x64).

Update Bundler: After running the command, update Bundler by executing gem install bundler.


